# How to configure my node.js application on a dedicated server to put it online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I've installed node.js on my server(it is a virtual windows server). I am also having the domain. I want to run my node.js application on a port 8001 so that when I open, say http://example.com:8001/ it will open my application.

Actually, I am also having a PHP site running on Apache server on port 80(XAMPP). It is perfectly working fine when I open say, http://example.com.

Thanks

Comment: Bonus Info: PHP doesn't actually run on 80, your Apache server does. Apache "communicates" with your PHP script (typically) via CGI (now-a-days it is FastCGI). If you run PHP-FPM instead of CGI, then you'd configure a reverse proxy to communicate with PHP-FPM on port 9000 (by default).

Answer (score 1):

In apache, create a new vhost. You have to proxy all requests through apache to your node app as apache is listening to port 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8001/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there any way to host the application without Apache because I will be uninstalling it anyway. What I want to achieve is when I open http://example.com:[PORT] it will run my node app, eventually running multiple node apps on different ports. Note: My server ip address is already being linked to the domain if that matters.

Comment: @nole, as I stated in my answer you can just start the app and it will be available from the port you defined it to run, ie. your code says `server.listen(8001);`, you say `node server.js`, and then it answers from that port.

Comment: @nole If you intend to have more than 1 node application listening on your box, you must use some sort of vhost and proxy. Whether it be a master node process that listens to 80 and delegates the connections based on host or a very lightweight proxy like nginx (which I recommend if you're glued to apache) to handle incoming connections.

Comment: @SamT Thanks. Also, I have tried your method to proxy the traffic to node app in Apache itself but its giving an internal server error. What could be the reason?

Comment: There could literally be hundreds of reasons why apache does that. Usually it's due to a bad configuration. Check your apache error logs to see whats up.

Comment: @SamT One does not need vhosts/proxies if they want to run **and** access their servers from different ports. This is what nole said earlier: _What I want to achieve is when I open example.com:[PORT] it will run my node app [...]_. You will only need vhost if you want to run them all from port 80.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on a name-based virtual host environment you can just start your Node.js server and it will be available to the world from the defined port. But if the server IP address runs many services using different domain names and you want your Node.js server to reply only from http://example.com:8001 you can use e.g. the `vhost` module on your node server to listen to specific domain only:

```
var express = require('express'),
    host = require('vhost');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello from vhost");
});

var main = express();
main.use(vhost('example.com', app));

if (!module.parent) {
  main.listen(8001);
}
```

You can also proxy the requests through a web server like Apache or nginx, but to have the service responding from port 8001 you would need to bind the web server to port 8001 in addition to 80 you are already using, and run your Node.js server on some other port.

Generally people prefer using the standard HTTP port and use a web server to reverse proxy traffic to the Node.js server running on a non-privileged port. As you already have the PHP application on your domain name you would then follow advice by @SamT and run your Node.js application from e.g. http://mynodeapp.example.com